# Android: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color

Tags: java, android, kotlin, color

при постройки проекта выскакивает ошибка, указанная в названии темы. направляет сюда:

```
 if (arrList[position].color != null){
            holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(arrList[position].color))
        }else{
            holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(R.color.ColorLightBlack.toString()))
        }
```

если убрать условие, которое написано в else, то проект запускается без ошибок.  Пробовал менять цвет, ничего не изменилось!

Comment: А зачем toString?

Comment: А сразу нельзя текст поставить ?`holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.ColorLightBlack)`

Comment: Переменная Color принимает строковое значение

Comment: @ArchDemon поставил, но показывается предупреждение:
Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here: getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightBlack)

Comment: должно быть вида: 
holder.itemView.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#636161")); 
или 
holder.itemView.cardView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_green_tea));
Думаю, в вашем случае переменная color обязательно должна быть - строка.